# Finding All The Cosets Of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory

> let $G=S_3$ and $H=\langle (\begin{smallmatrix} 
> 1 & 2 & 3\\
> 2 & 1 & 3
> \end{smallmatrix}) \rangle$, Find all the left and right cosets of $H$

What I have done is to take every $\sigma\in S_3$ else from  $(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3
\end{smallmatrix})$ and  $(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3
\end{smallmatrix})$ as they are both in $H$ and compose it from the left and the right, What I have got is:

**Left Cosets**

$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
1& 3 & 2\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3& 1 & 2\end{smallmatrix})$

$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2& 3 & 1\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3& 2 & 1\end{smallmatrix})$

$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3& 1 & 2\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
1& 3 & 2\end{smallmatrix})$

$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3& 2 & 1\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2& 3 & 1\end{smallmatrix})$

**Right Costs**

$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2& 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 2\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2& 3 & 1\end{smallmatrix})$

$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2& 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 3 & 1\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
1& 3 & 2\end{smallmatrix})$

$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2& 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3 & 1 & 2\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3& 2 & 1\end{smallmatrix})$

$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2& 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3 & 2 & 1\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3& 1 & 2\end{smallmatrix})$

Is this correct? Is it true that we can not use Lagrange’s theorem to calculate the number of cosets?

Comment: It seems to me as though you haven't properly understood the problem.  Do you understand that 
$$
H = \left \langle\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3}\right \rangle = \left \{ \pmatrix{1&2&3\\1&2&3}, \pmatrix{1&2&3\\2&1&3}\right\}?
$$

Comment: We should find, as in Lagrange's theorem, that there are $|G|/|H| = 6/2 = 3$ cosets of each kind.

Comment: Yes, that it why I did not take those elements in the cosets

Comment: Okay, you should then also observe that
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2}H = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\3&2&1}H
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so I have one more in each, how can I find who to remove?

Comment: Also, note that $H$ is considered to be a coset of $H$ (perhaps a "trivial coset").

Comment: I got $(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3& 1 & 2\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
1& 3 & 2\end{smallmatrix})$
And 
$(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
3& 2 & 1\end{smallmatrix})\circ (\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3\end{smallmatrix})=(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2& 3 & 1\end{smallmatrix})$

Comment: Composition of permutations is usually done from right to left (as with functions), not left to right

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So how can we differ left and right cosets in $S_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, one left-coset of $H$ is 
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2}H =\\ 
\left\{\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2} \circ \pmatrix{1&2&3\\1&2&3},  
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2} \circ \pmatrix{1&2&3\\2&1&3}\right\} = \\
\left\{\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2},  
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&2&1}\right\}
$$
Note that this is precisely the same left-coset as 
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\3&2&1}H =\\
\left\{\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&2&1} \circ \pmatrix{1&2&3\\1&2&3},  
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&2&1} \circ \pmatrix{1&2&3\\2&1&3}\right\} = \\
\left\{\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&2&1},  
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2}\right\}
$$
On the other hand, we would compute the corresponding right-coset as
$$
H\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2} =\\ 
\left\{ \pmatrix{1&2&3\\1&2&3} \circ \pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2},  
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\2&1&3} \circ \pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2}\right\} = \\
\left\{\pmatrix{1&2&3\\3&1&2},  
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\1&3&2}\right\}
$$
You may verify that this is the same right-coset as $H\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2&3\\1&3&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.